# CLOSED OpenMPI: Error while mpirun on multiple hosts

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi

I have configured two host with ompi, and I am able to run below sample code successfully in both seperately

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(argc,argv)
int argc;
char *argv[];  {
int numtasks, rank, dest, source, rc, count, tag=1;
char inmsg, outmsg='x';
MPI_Status Stat;

MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

if (rank == 0) {
  dest = 1;
  source = 1;
  rc = MPI_Send(&outmsg, 1, MPI_CHAR, dest, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  rc = MPI_Recv(&inmsg, 1, MPI_CHAR, source, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Stat);
}

else if (rank == 1) {
  dest = 0;
  source = 0;
  rc = MPI_Recv(&inmsg, 1, MPI_CHAR, source, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Stat);
  rc = MPI_Send(&outmsg, 1, MPI_CHAR, dest, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}

rc = MPI_Get_count(&Stat, MPI_CHAR, &count);
printf("Task %d: Received %d char(s) from task %d with tag %d \n",
   rank, count, Stat.MPI_SOURCE, Stat.MPI_TAG);

MPI_Finalize();
}
```

> mpirun -np 2 sendReceive.o

works fine.

> mpirun -np 2 --host host1,host1 sendReceive.o

```
[ip-172-31-71-xx:11221] [[55975,0],1] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Data unpack would read past end of buffer in file base/odls_base_default_fns.c at line 398
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ORTE has lost communication with a remote daemon.

  HNP daemon   : [[55975,0],0] on node ip-172-31-78-xx
  Remote daemon: [[55975,0],1] on node ip-172-31-71-xx

This is usually due to either a failure of the TCP network
connection to the node, or possibly an internal failure of
the daemon itself. We cannot recover from this failure, and
therefore will terminate the job.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I verified i can ssh between the host and configured correctly. I am     not able to narrow down to the problem here. any suggestion?

Answer: by mistake I take different version of mpi in each system. when i correct the version, its working !!!

Comment: at first, try `
mpirun -np 2 --host host1,host1 hostname`
and see if it works

btw, which version of Open MPI are you running ?

Comment: Tried that first. no it's not working

Comment: you can try `mpirun -np 2 --host host1,host1 --mca oob_tcp_base_verbose 100 hostname` and post the logs and the Open MPI version you are running (note you need more connectivity than ssh between nodes).

Comment: Seems i was using different version of mpi between machines. working when i use the same.

Answer (score 1):

You have to allow your security groups to pass mpi communication within hosts. You can fix this by first limitting your MPI communication to a specific port range and allowing this port range in your Security Group under Custom TCP port range. Then you should be able to work this as expected. To limit the port range, refer [openmpi-mca-params.conf](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=tuning) (According to the configuration file:)

> By default, two files are searched (in order):
>
> `$HOME/.openmpi/mca-params.conf`: The user-supplied set of values takes the highest precedence.
>
> `$prefix/etc/openmpi-mca-params.conf`: The system-supplied set of values has a lower precedence.

To allow security groups to communicate custom TCP ports,

1. Go to EC2 management console
2. Go to Security Groups
   [image]
3. Select the relavant security group and under inbound connections, click edit.[image]
4. Add the port range you selected early.[image]

Comment: security groups are open between these instances.